# How to access single sprite in array of sprites?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

How do I access the first sprite in an array of sprites and change it's location to this?

```
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *aSprite;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *sprites;
```

one for the sprite one array to hold them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the first object in an array of sprites you can do this:

```
SKSpriteNode *object = [myArray firstObject];
object.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));
```

To access all objects in an array do this:

```
for(SKSpriteNode *object in myArray) {
    object.position = CGPointMake(arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.width), arc4random_uniform(self.frame.size.height));
}
```